# Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter browsers not returning proper viewport height

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, instagram, viewport

I've been looking for a fix for this that works across all of these social browsers or at least facebook for the last few weeks and have yet to figure anything out or find anything helpful. The last few posts I've looked at that setup resize functions have failed to work for me.

I've tried

JS

```
function _fixViewportHeight() {
    var html = document.querySelector('html');

    function _onResize(event) {
        html.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', _.debounce(_onResize, 125, {
        leading: true,
        maxWait: 250,
        trailing: true
    }));

    _onResize();
}

_fixViewportHeight();
```

CSS

```
html, body, .fullpage-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
```

Also tried This JS

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  onResize();
});

function onResize(){
  document.querySelector("html").style.height = window.innerHeight + "px"
 setTimeout(function(){$(window).scrollTop(0)}, 1000);
};

onResize();
```

Was wondering if maybe this script I saw somewhere could work - but I'm not sure how to properly implement it.

```
FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
    function(info) {
        alert('Width: ' + info.clientWidth + ' Height: ' + info.clientHeight);
    }
);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.getPageInfo/

Can someone please help me with this, I will hire someone at this point.

What it's supposed to look like

[image]

What Facebooks browser crops/cuts off.

[image]

Comment: _"Was wondering if maybe this script I saw somewhere could work"_ - nope; that’s for Canvas apps, which yours isn’t. // Any reason why this would need any JS interference in the first place? Are there any resize events happening on those devices anyway?

Comment: @CBroe Ahh thanks for that! Because Facebook and other social browsers don't seem to calculate their headers/footers in the viewport height. The resize event is when the headers and footers come into the screen/viewport

Comment: @alcoven did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: have you tried to make an element 100% height and then measure its effective height ?

Answer (score 1):

This is common problem with viewport not specific to "preview" browser

I found https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill quite efficient. You only have to include .js file and initialize it

```
viewportUnitsBuggyfill.init({
  force: true, // use for debug on desktop
  refreshDebounceWait: 300 // good for performance
});
```

Comment: May be you should explain how this buggyfill (packed with many fixes for different issues) addresses this particular issue. I would be helpful!